# Convert number to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

How do I Convert "1561994754" number to "2019-07-01T15:25:54.000000"

I have used :

```
import datetime    
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x['date'] / 1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But I am getting `1970-01-18 19:53:14.754000`, can you please guide me to correct function?

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: tried `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x['date'], tz=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()`?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `/ 1000` gives me `'2019-07-01 08:25:54.000000'`, It seems like there was a unit mismatch in your expression. To exactly match the format you're asking for, `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x['date'], tz=datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')` produces `'2019-07-01T15:25:54.000000` (leaving the timezone argument blank defaults to using local time, but the human-readable date in your question uses UTC)

Comment: It is giving me OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: are you sure you copied it correctly? I just re-copied that line and it works fine for me. I first ran `import datetime`, then `x = {'date': 1561994754}` and finally the long expression in my answer, and that gave me `'2019-07-01T15:25:54.000000'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this!

```
String myString = String.valueOf(1561994754);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = format.parse(myString);
```

Comment: Which language is this? The tag is for python. This seems like java or so

Comment: @DebDas I need it in Python

Comment: `import pandas as pd

new_dict = {'no_dates':  [19990320,20200416,20010828],
          'new_stats': ['Available','Available','Available']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict, columns = ['no_dates','new_stats'])

df['no_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['no_dates'], format='%Y%m%d')

print (df)`  @PadmajaKattamuri

Comment: Please refer to https://pythonguides.com/convert-integers-to-datetime-in-pandas/